# insert HEX in to file with PHP

Tags: php, hex, fopen

I have a tool in PHP that I made to automate the process of generating some hex, which I then manually place in a file using a hex editor.

I have 1 byte which goes to offset 0x345, and a much larger section of varying length which goes to 0x560.  I use Paste > Write so that the hex I generated replaces what is in it's way rather then increase the size of the file.

Is there a way I can automate this with `fopen();` so that I can skip the manual pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these functions: `fopen` to open file, `fseek` to desired positions and `fwrite` your data.

Comment: I've had these working flawlessly for a while now.  I had to change my mindset for it.. Convert the hex to binary and `fseek` to a position that had no bearing on my original offset.  But with that in place, it's working great and saving me a lot of time.  Many thanks!